# How to perform a calculation for all columns of a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, lag

I have a matrix with tree ring width for 66 trees. Rows represent the years of measurement and columns represent the different trees.

Now I want to calculate the growth difference from one year to another tree by tree. I managed to do that with the "lag" function from `dplyr` for each column separately. That's a lot code to write for 66 columns, so I am looking for a way to do that for all columns at once but column-wise.

my 'treegrowth' data.frame looks like this:

```
year tree1 tree2 tree3 ...
1900 0.72 0.34 1.34
1901 0.56 0.88 0.98
1902 1.23 0.56 1.67
...
```

For each tree I want to divide the value of one year by the value of the previous year and subset the old value with the result.

I can do that for each column like this:

```
  treegrowth$tree1 <- treegrowth$tree1 / lag(treegrowth$tree1)
```

But how can I manage this in one step for all trees (columns)?

If I just leave out the `'$tree1'` something strange is happening but not what I want to have.

```
> dput(head(treegrowth))
structure(list(WA12M = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), WA81M = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA101M = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), HA263M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), HA358M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), HA386M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), HA387M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), HA388M = c(0.73, 
0.73, 0.84, 0.43, 0.67, 0.72), HA390M = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), HA420M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), MI49M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), MI51M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), MI62M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), MI309M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), NO4M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), NO8M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), NO23M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), NO42M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), NO47M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), NO50M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), NO73M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA3M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA18M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA22M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA25M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA26M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA27M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA28M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA38M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA40M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA48M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA64M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA80M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA84M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA88M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA90M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA93M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA95M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA103M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA104M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA111M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA141M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA142M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA154M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA163M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA164M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA177M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA194M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA195M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA196M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA197M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA198M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA200M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA202M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA205M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA206M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA207M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA225M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA252M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA291M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA294M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA297M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA299M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA376M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA379M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WA395M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), EI33M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), EI38M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), HA161M = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names`c("1803", 
"1804", "1805", "1806", "1807", "1808"), class = c("rwl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: `sapply(treegrowth[-1], function(x) x/lag(x))`

Answer (score 5):

Using base R, we can use `lapply`

```
treegrowth[paste0(names(df[-1]), "_growth")] <- lapply(treegrowth[-1], 
                  function(x) c(NA, x[-1]/x[-length(x)]))

#  year tree1 tree2 tree3 tree1_growth tree2_growth tree3_growth
#1 1900  0.72  0.34  1.34           NA           NA           NA
#2 1901  0.56  0.88  0.98    0.7777778    2.5882353    0.7313433
#3 1902  1.23  0.56  1.67    2.1964286    0.6363636    1.7040816
```

Or if you want to use `dplyr` and `lag`, we can use `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
treegrowth %>% mutate_at(-1, list(growth = ~./lag(.)))
```

**data**

```
treegrowth <- structure(list(year = 1900:1902, tree1 = c(0.72, 0.56, 1.23), 
tree2 = c(0.34, 0.88, 0.56), tree3 = c(1.34, 0.98, 1.67)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thank you! The 'mutate_at' way is working, but I loose the year-names with that. Can you also help with that?

Comment: @ansa What do you mean by "year-names", the first column ? Seems to remain same for me. What is `class(treegrowth$year)` ? Do you have any other columns than shown ?

Comment: Sorry for my unclear asking. I'm new to R. I have written the table down wrongly, the years are not the first column but the names of the rows. Is that better to understand? And if I use your code, the resulting rows are numbered from one to 214 (cause i have data for 214 years) but the exact year is missing. Also the calculation is not done for the first tree. I guessed it's because of the "-1" in your code, to exclude the first column because you thought it's the years, right?

Comment: @ansa So do you want to exclude two columns then? You can do `treegrowth[-c(1:2)]` for that. With `dplyr` it is easy, you can do `treegrowth %>% mutate_at(-c(1, 2), list(growth = ~./lag(.)))` so that 1st two columns are ignored.

Comment: No, I did not want to exclude any columns. I wanted to do the calculation on all columns but remain the rownames, which are the years.

Comment: @ansa can you share dput(treegrowth)? It's quite difficult to debug without data.

Comment: I don't get, how to share the actual data .rwl, but here is part of it: WA12M   1980   409   507   725    40    62   329   323   229   326   242
WA12M   1990   122   327   275   151   270   149   151   193   155   135
WA12M   2000   150   165   234   230   158    68    60    60    52    36
WA12M   2010    63    64    65    74    82    64   999

Comment: @ansa once you read the data into R, name it say (`treegrowth`), then use `dput(head(treegrowth))` and copy it here.

Comment: @ansa your `dput` is not correct. If you check my answer in the last part I have mentioned **data** followed by `treegrowth <- structure....` if you copy that and paste in your R session and then type `treegrowth` you'll see an exact dataframe which I have used to answer. We need something similar which we can copy-paste into our R session. Currently your `dput` is incomplete. Also looks like most of the values in your column are `NA`.

Answer (score 2):

The zoo package has `diff.zoo` which with the `arithmetic=FALSE` argument does exactly that.   Using `treegrowth` given reproducibly in the Note at the end we use the following code which read it into a zoo object and then applies `diff`.

(Note that `fortify.zoo` will convert a zoo object to a data frame if you need that.)

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(as.data.frame(treegrowth))
zd <- diff(z, arithmetic = FALSE)
```

giving this zoo object:

```
zd
##          tree1     tree2     tree3
## 1901 0.7777778 2.5882353 0.7313433
## 1902 2.1964286 0.6363636 1.7040816

library(ggplot2)

autoplot(zd, facet = NULL) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = time(zd)) +
  xlab("year")
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

```
Lines <- "year tree1 tree2 tree3
1900 0.72 0.34 1.34
1901 0.56 0.88 0.98
1902 1.23 0.56 1.67"
treegrowth <- as.matrix(read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the format of your dataframe to a long format with a melt function (from the reshape2 package).
Once in a long format you can perform your calculation easily with a loop.

If your treename becomes your variable you could write something like

```
for (tree in levels(treegrowth_m$variable)){
    treegrowth_m$tree <- treegrowth_m$tree / lag(treegrowth_m$tree)
}
```

where treegrowth_m is your melted df

Answer (score 0):

If you reshape your data to a longer format, this becomes easier:

```r
df %>% 
  gather("tree", "width", -year) %>% 
  group_by(tree) %>% 
  mutate(growth = width / lag(width))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code:

```
treeGrowth <- data.frame("year"=c(1900, 1901, 1902), 
                         "tree1"=c(0.72, 0.56, 1.23), 
                         "tree2"=c(0.34, 0.88, 0.56), 
                         "tree3"=c(1.34, 0.98, 1.67))

for(column in colnames(treeGrowth)[-1]){
    treeGrowth[, paste0(column, "_growth")] <- c(NA, treeGrowth[-1, column] /     
                                                     treeGrowth[-nrow(data), 
                                                                column])
}

print(treeGrowth)

#  year tree1 tree2 tree3 tree1_growth tree2_growth tree3_growth
#1 1900  0.72  0.34  1.34    1.0000000    1.0000000    1.0000000
#2 1901  0.56  0.88  0.98    0.7777778    2.5882353    0.7313433
#3 1902  1.23  0.56  1.67    2.1964286    0.6363636    1.7040816
```